# How can I get selected text from safari in it's app exension?

Tags: swift, safari

How can I get selected text from safari in safari app exension?
here is my code , but receive nothing from webpage . did somebody has the example code that is save the selected text with safari app extension ?

my safari is version 12  and  xcode is version 10.3

```
import SafariServices

class SafariExtensionHandler: SFSafariExtensionHandler {
    override func contextMenuItemSelected(withCommand command: String, in page: SFSafariPage, userInfo: [String : Any]? = nil) {
        var str2 : String = "The extension received a message (\(command)) from a script injected into (\(String(describing: properties?.url))) with userInfo (\(userInfo ?? [:]))"
        NSLog(str2)

        do{
            let documentpath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.downloadsDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
            var p1 : String = documentpath[0] + "/gg1.txt"
            try str2.write(toFile: p1, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        }
        catch let error {
            print(error)
        } 
}
...........
```

the script.js is :

```
'use strict';

document.addEventListener('contextmenu', (event) => {
    var selectedText = window.getSelection().toString();
    safari.extension.setContextMenuEventUserInfo(event,{ "selectedText": selectedText });
}
```